# How to make content div full screen

Tags: html, css, fullscreen

I have html page ,container div contain header ,content and footer div ,the html cod and css code is like this:

**HTML-Code:**

```
  <html>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content">
    <div class="content2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
    </html>
```

Css code:

```
header{
padding-bottom:5px;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
top:0;
z-index:100;
height:70px;
background-color:#006}

.content{
min-height: 100%;
width:100%;
background-color:#006;
margin-top:70px;
margin-bottom:60px }

.content2{
margin:auto;
min-height: 100%;
width:95%;
background-color:#FFFEA5;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.footer{
text-align:center;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
z-index:100;
height:70px;
background-color:#006}
```

I want the content2 div be full screen either it didn't contain anything ,i did codes above but didn't work ,it is appear like attached image.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what the different `div` elements would contain so it is easier to see which div is affecting the height?

Comment: @TylerHarrison Sir as shown in image .content div don't be full screen ,i want to be fill between header and footer

Comment: Possibly a `margin-bottom: //whatever minus amout` as in get the height of the gap and make a minus margin, then `padding-bottom: //whatever amout` to fill in that gap.

Comment: You want `div.content2` to cover the whole screen ? try `height:100vh`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to put all those divs to a parent div like  and set to that div 100% width and height(height is not necessary, it will set 100% too) and then you will have div container occupying all screen.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing and need body tag (among other things) which will set whole background to blue.

```css
body{
background-color:#006
}

header{
padding-bottom:5px;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
top:0;
z-index:100;
height:70px;
background-color:#006}

.content{
min-height: 100%;
width:100%;
background-color:#006;
margin-top:70px;
margin-bottom:60px }

.content2{
margin:auto;
min-height: 100%;
width:95%;
background-color:#FFFEA5;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.footer{
text-align:center;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
z-index:100;
height:70px;
background-color:#006}
```

```html
  <html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content">
    <div class="content2">test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
     </body> 
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of you ,i changed css files and made it like this ,and it is works now :

```
 .header{
    padding-bottom:5px;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    z-index:100;
    height:70px;
    background-color:#006}
.footer{
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:100;
    height:70px;
    background-color:#006}
.content{
    min-height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#FFFEA5;
    margin-top:70px;
    margin-bottom:60px }
.content2{
    height: 100%;
    margin:auto;
    width:95%;
    background-color:#FFFEA5;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}
.wrapperDiv{
    background-color: #006;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height: 100%;
        }
```